# BI/Anaytics Technique for SOA based products using MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, analytics, soa, business-intelligence

I am looking for BI/Analytic options for my application.

My application is online/mobile food-ordering application. So three type of stack holders are involved:

1. Guest - who order the food.
2. Restaurant - who delivered the food.
3. We - as a online platform provider.

We have used SOA architecture. We have used nodejs as service langauge and mongoDB as database.

Now we want to add BI related facilities in the system. We consider following items:
 - Reports
 - charts
 - Dashboards

The BI and analytic field is quite new for us and so Looking forward for two questions:

1. what kind of reports/charts/analytic is useful for this kind of application, which is related to hospitality? This might not be pure programming question but if someone has experience with this kind of system, they can guide me.
2. What kind of architecture, I should use?
   I tried/considered following approach but I am not 100% aware about the pros and cons of those approach with respect to my system (SOA with mongoDB).

   - Pentaho Data Integration Services (or any other BI tools such as jaspersoft)
   - Web service based approach with map-reduce, socket.io service and HTML5 based mechanism to develop front end part.

While studying pentaho, I found that it is very powerful system and provides lot of facility while tweaking with data. But I have question is, when I have large amount of data is stored in form of mongoDB, what kind of advantage, I can get by using pentaho or any other BI tool such as jaspersoft?

Another option is to create one analytics web service using conventional programming language (nodejs or python) and it uses map-reduce technique to generate the required information and that will be displayed via any HTML5 based front end mechanism.

Basically what advantage I can get by using BI product, if I use them in my application context?

As I said earlier, I am very naive with analytics concept and so kindly let me know, if I am missing anything here.

Thanks in Advance.